# Its possible use special characters in a shell function name?

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, function

I have to create the function in shell script, that function name must contain the special characters. like

```
     >()
      {
       echo $1 $2
      }
```

Here my function name is `>`, If its possible how can I give, Like above I tried that But it will through the error

Comment: This is probably an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Why do you need a function called `>`?

Comment: @jofel I need to add the function in bashrc file, when redirection symbol is occur on my terminal window I need to call that function.

Comment: We are getting closer. Can you elaborate more? Do you need this for debugging? `bash` accepts only one argument after `>` so why do you use `$1` and `$2`? The answer to your actually question is probably actually *no*, but it is not yet clear what you really want to achieve.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what your final objective is. What exactly do you want to achieve with this function? Calling a function `>` is not a solution, if you explain what you are trying to do, we might be able to help you find another way.

Comment: Learning is like the sky... it never ends.;)

Answer (score 2):

Most shells restrict the name of functions to contain only characters that don't need to be quoted, which excludes `>`.

Even in the few shells that allow `>` as a function name (I only know of zsh), defining a function called `>` would only have an effect if you called `>` as a command (which would require quoting it, i.e. running `\>` or `">"` or `'>'`). It would not change how redirection works.

None of the usual shells have a way to configure what happens if some subsequent part of the script performs a redirection. If you need that kind of things, a shell is not nearly a flexible enough language. But there's probably a better way to solve [whatever problem you're trying to solve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) — and quite possibly one that can be solved in a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

The `>` has a special meaning in the shell, it's a redirection operator, see the manpage:

> [n]> file   Redirect standard output (or n) to file.

The name of a function can contain only letters (a-z or A-Z), digit (0-9) or the underscore character (_). Also is must not begin with a digit. (see [Function Definition Command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_05) and [Name](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_230))